# Subsection prefix, spacing issues at ToC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, appendices

For my report I want to use a prefix for the appendices.

To do so, I have this piece of code:

```
\appendix
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{Appendix~\Roman{subsection}:}
```

This seems to work fine for any `\subsection{Title}` that I use, except for the Table of Content, which is generated with `\tableofcontents`.
The issue is that the title of the subsection is overlapping the prefix in the ToC. How can I fix this spacing issue?

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{Appendix~\Roman{subsection}:}
\subsection{Some schematics}
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC Spacing issue]

Comment: Please provide a minimal compilable example, starting at `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Has been added.